# How to incorporate the chat history in a CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I have a langchain agent that I am trying to incorporate chat history in. I have used the below code:-

```
    agent_kwargs = {

  'prefix': f'''Answer the questions to provide relevant information to a etc etc

  Begin!

  ''',

  "extra_prompt_messages": [MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="memory")]}
```

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="memory", return_messages=True)

```
# initialize the LLM agent

agent = initialize_agent(tools,

                         llm,

                         agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,

                         verbose=True,

                         agent_kwargs=agent_kwargs,

                         memory=memory,

                         )

agent.run({user_question})
```

Upon running this, I get the error
ValueError: A single string input was passed in, but this chain expects multiple inputs ({'input', 'chat_history'}). When a chain expects multiple inputs, please call it by passing in a dictionary, eg `chain({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})`

Please let me know what variable I should be passing for the chat history input. I cannot use OPENAI_FUNCTIONS in place of CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION.Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the prompt as used in this doc (https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/agent_with_memory). I used it with create_react_agent() though.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35853730)